# Angular multiple select not preselecting for non-empty ng-model

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have `$scope.selectedUsers` set as an array with just 1 object, which is an exact match of one of the objects from my available list of all `$scope.users`, altho the selected user is not highlighted in my `<select multiple...>`. Shouldn't it be highlighted?

**Js:**

```
$scope.selectedUsers = [ 
    { id: 2, name: "Jenny" }
];

$scope.users = [ 
  { id: 1, name: "Frank" },
  { id: 2, name: "Jenny" }     
];
```

**Html:**

```
<select multiple ng-model="selectedUsers" ng-options="user as user.name for user in users"></select>
```

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/wpfvhvuShFVE07cyBE6M?p=preview

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which is an exact match of one of the objects from my available list of all $scope.users

No, they are not the **same** even though both objects has similar key-values. Angular uses strict comparison of objects (`===`) and two objects are equal only if they are the same object (references the same object).

Correct code in your case:

```
$scope.users = [ 
  { id: 1, name: "Frank" },
  { id: 2, name: "Jenny" }
];

$scope.selectedUsers = [ 
  $scope.users[1]
];
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Czb7JuUzl7dPa08gsqUD?p=preview